# Unable to print Class Name using querySelector()

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am having trouble printing class name using querySelector() instead it is printing whole element. I know I'm missing some small attribute but can't figure out as I'm coding after long time so unable to recall.

It is printing

> The Class Name is: SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }, SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my html file

```
<lightning-layout-item>
    <input 
        type="text"
        class="
            slds-input
            slds-text-align_center
            slds-var-m-bottom_large
            firstName
        "
        value={firstName}
        placeholder="First Name">
</lightning-layout-item>
<lightning-layout-item>
    <input 
        type="text"
        class="
            slds-input
            slds-text-align_center
            slds-var-m-bottom_large
            lastName
        "
        value={lastName}
        placeholder="Last Name">
</lightning-layout-item>
```

and js file

```
const firstNameClass = this.template.querySelector('.firstName');
const lastNameClass = this.template.querySelector('.lastName');
console.log(`The Class Name is: ${firstNameClass}, ${lastNameClass}`);
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `className`:

```
const firstNameClass = this.template.querySelector('.firstName').className;
const lastNameClass = this.template.querySelector('.lastName').className;
console.log(`The Class Name is: ${firstNameClass}, ${lastNameClass}`);
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you @sfdcfox!